# how to check if an array has the same number

Tags: c#

I wanted this program to print out random numbers (1-6) in Columns forever until all the rows of each columns have the exact same number. If the user enters 5 forexample, it will print out 5 columns of random numbers (1-6) until each row of that 5 columns are the same . I am stuck, I don't know how to check all the elements of the array, whether or not they are all the same with one another.

```
namespace Dice_Roll_2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int userinput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Random Dice = new Random();
            bool search = true;

            while (search)
            {
                var output = string.Empty;
                int[] numberofdice = new int[userinput+1];

                for (int i = 1; i <=userinput; i++)
                {
                    numberofdice[i] = Dice.Next(1, 7);
                    output += numberofdice[i];
                    if (i < userinput )
                    {
                        output += "\0";

                    }

                    if (numberofdice[i-1] == numberofdice[i])
                    {
                        search = false;
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine(output);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `Linq` namespace, you can do a `Distinct()` on your array of columns and when the `Count()` of the `Distinct()` equals 1, then all the columns are the same and you can stop rolling.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number of columns: ");
        int userinput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] columns = new int[userinput];

        Random Dice = new Random();
        bool search = true;

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        while (search)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
            {
                columns[i] = Dice.Next(1, 7);
            }

            if (columns.Distinct().Count() == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("All columns match with the value of {0}", columns[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("It took {0} to get all columns to match", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start));
                search = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results (Time span and value will vary on each run):

```
Enter number of columns: 5
All columns match with the value of 4
It took 00:00:00.0156260 to get all columns to match
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V1SSmI) is limited to 7 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing should begin with 0. To check that all elements are the same, you can use a loop to compare each element with the first.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int userinput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Random Dice = new Random();
    int[] numberofdice = new int[userinput + 1];

    while(true)
    {
        var output = string.Empty;

        // Generate the userinput random numbers
        // as well as output string
        for(int i = 0; i < userinput; i++)
        {
            numberofdice[i] = Dice.Next(1, 7);
            output += numberofdice[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        // Check that they are all same by comparing with first
        bool same = true;
        int first = numberofdice[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < userinput; i++)
        {
            if(numberofdice[i] != first)
            {
                same = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If all were the same, stop.
        if(same)
            break;
    }
}
```